# how to modify child/foreign key ids of existing records without saving them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models

```
model A
  has_many :b

model B
```

For new records, I can do this:

```
new_record = A.new
new_record.b_ids = [5] # ids will not attempt to save
new_record.save
```

But for existing records:

```
existing_record = A.find(...)
existing_record.b_ids = [5] # after this assignment, database already updates (using SQL if that matters)
```

How do I modify existing_record child ids without updating the database. I want to save it only when I run "existing_record.save." I noticed :autosave but it looks like that is a little different from what I'm asking for right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model A
  has_many :b
model B
```

has_many association gives you `collection_singular_ids=(ids)` method  and this is one of the setter methods.

Now secondly, to make this work you need to declare `belongs_to :a` in `model B`

[For has_many reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

Comment: thanks, i should have known about that earlier. still not sure what's a good way to reach my goal using that though.

Comment: the thing is if you want to relate two table then you need to store one column of A table to B table , now the column might be name or id or anything , but according to convention , storing the id is best way .